# Net speed indicator for Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: 15.04, software-recommendation, indicator, network-monitoring

What are some net speed indicator available for **Ubuntu 15.04** and how to install them?

Comment: @Raphael none of those are indicator applets

Comment: @Ravan: Please retract close vote: none of the duplicate are indicator applets.

Comment: @ParanoidPanda: ------^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `indicator-multiload` for this. To install, run the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install indicator-multiload
```

Now, run `indicator-multiload`:

```
indicator-multiload & disown
```

Then, click on the indicator and select preferences to customize the output. You can display graphs, text or both for many different areas and not just netspeed.

[image: Screenshot indicator-multiload]

Comment: I like this, but I wish I could make the network speed number appear in the indicator itself.

Answer (score 0):

To add the Netspeed Unity Indicator use the following commands:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:fixnix/netspeed 
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install indicator-netspeed-unity
```